# Solving the exact differential equation y'=(x-y)/(x+y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I need to solve the following exact equation:

$y' = \frac{(x-y)}{(x+y)}$

I've been taught to put those in the form $M(x, y)dx + N(x, y)dy = 0$ and to make sure ${dM}\over{dy}$ = ${dN}\over{dx}$

So I transform the equation into
$\frac{1}{(x+y)} dx + \frac{1}{(y-x)}dy=0$

However, $\frac{dM}{dy}=\frac{-1}{(y+x)^2}$ and $\frac{dN}{dx}=\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}$

They are not equal? I'm not supposed to use an integrating factor either.. so I'm a bit at a loss :(

The answer is supposed to be $x^2 -2xy -y^2 = c$

How do I get there?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Why not $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-y}{x+y} \implies (x+y) dy = (x-y) dx \implies (y-x)dx + (x+y)dy = 0$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing the algebra differently:
$$-(x-y)dx+(x+y)dy=0\ .$$
Can you take it from here?

BTW if your instructor **really** wants you not to use an integrating factor, this is no good: we have multiplied both sides by $x+y$, which **is** an integrating factor even though we did not need to find it by any complicated method.

**Comment**.  Since you have been told the solution, you could work out the method by "reverse-engineering" the answer: just take your solution
$$x^2-2xy-y^2=C$$
and differentiate with respect to $x$ to get
$$(2x-2y)dx-(2x+2y)dy=0\ ;$$
this gives you the hint as to how to start solving the DE.

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks.. I guess I'm rusty :( Thanks for the reverse-engineering tip! I'll try that if I'm stuck on other exercises :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if you are obliged to go through these steps; so forgive me if what I write is not an answer to your post.

The differential equation simplifies a lot if you define $x+y=z$; so $y=z-x$, $y'=z'-1$ and the rhs write $\frac {2x-z}{z}=\frac {2x}{z}-1$. Simplifying then leads to $$z z'=2x$$which, by integration of both sides, leads to $$z^2=2x^2+C$$ Back to the definition of $z$,$$(x+y)^2=2x^2+C$$ which, after development, leads to $$x^2 -2xy -y^2 = C$$